# How to get exception occurring in a polling thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am using the concurrent.futures module and my code looks like this

```
class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    executor.submit(self._start_polling())

  def _start_polling(self):
    while True:
      # polling some stuff

  def get_stuff(self):
    # returns some stuff
```

I will be using this class to `get_stuff()` multiple times in my code and I need to polling to make sure I always get the latest stuff (the stuff changes from time to time by some other program). Now, if there occurs an exception in the polling thread, how do I raise it in the main thread and stop the entire program? Currently, if there's an exception the polling thread dies and `get_stuff()` returns stale data.
I tried getting the `future` object but if I use it in any way like `future.exception()` it just blocks the execution of the main thread on it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Edit**:
I first looked into asyncio to do this but after reading about it a bunch it looks like running a asyncio is not really good for running background tasks like this. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For your specific situation, if you need only one worker and do a long time task. Use a normal `Thread` would be better as it directly throws the exception.

Comment: Am sorry, what do you mean by use a normal Thread?

Comment: I mean this: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: I see, but that still will not stop the main thread right? Is there a way I can get my main thread to stop when I encounter an exception?

Comment: I think based on your current structure it would be difficult. Stop the main thread, in other words, it means that the main thread is monitoring the running status of the child thread. An event-based structure should be helpful.